# Finite State Machine to find Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: state-machines

Ok so here is the problem we are given:

Consider the following datapath. Assume the width of the datapath n is 4.

[image]

The ALU has a 1-bit operation code OP. If OP=0, the ALU performs A-B. If OP=1, the ALU performs B-A.
The Compare circuit generates a 2-bit comparison code CC. CC=00 if A=B. CC=01 if A>B. CC=10
if A <  B.
The  Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) of two positive integers can be found by the Euclid’s Algorithm,
which is given below:

```
LOAD A
LOAD B
WHILE (A != B) DO
IF (A > B) THEN
A = A – B
ELSE
B = B – A
```

// GCD(A, B) is stored in both registers A and B
Design a Mealy-type FSM to control the datapath to find the GCD of 14 and 4. The FSM should set an
output FOUND to 1 when the GCD is found.

I just don't get how to start making this GCD finder... Would love some help on this!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have all written down, you just need a couple of registers and a little combinational logic. I'll start writing down how I think you can do the machine defining inputs and outputs while designing it.

Let's say you start in your \$S_0\$ state, that's your "entry" state. First things first, load the two registers. On the first transition you will need:
$$\begin{cases}
\textbf{LDA}=1 & \textit{to write in A}\\
\textbf{LDB}=0 & \textit{you don't want to write in B}\\
\overline{\textbf{W}}=0 & \textit{to actually write}
\end{cases}$$
On the second one of course:
$$\begin{cases}
\textbf{LDB}=1 & \textit{to write in B}\\
\textbf{LDA}=0 & \textit{you don't want to write in A}\\
\overline{\textbf{W}}=0 & \textit{to actually write}
\end{cases}$$

You now are in another state, remember that you passed through a "silent" state. The last two transitions are conditionless, i.e. they do not depend on the inputs.

Let's call your current state \$S_L\$, L as in loop. We are now implementing the Euclid's algorithm just as you wrote it down. Firs of all the easiest thing: when A=B we need to exit the loop and tell the outside world we are done, so another transition would be:
$$\textbf{if }\textbf{CC}=00 \rightarrow S_{end},\ \textbf{F}=1,\ \textbf{LDA}=0,\ \textbf{LDB}=0$$
There are two more transitions of interest, the important input of course is CC:
$$\textbf{if }\textbf{CC}=01 \rightarrow S_{L}, \textbf{F}=0,\ \textbf{OP}=0,\ \textbf{W}=1,\ \textbf{LDA}=1,\ \textbf{LDB}=0$$
$$\textbf{if }\textbf{CC}=10 \rightarrow S_{L},\ \textbf{F}=0,\ \textbf{OP}=1,\ \textbf{W}=1,\ \textbf{LDA}=0,\ \textbf{LDB}=1$$
I'm calling "FOUND" just "F". All the outputs that are not specified in a transition can be treated as "don't cares"

Finally, about \$S_{end}\$, you might just want to stay in it keeping \$\textbf{F}=1\$.

Summing up:

**States**: \$S_0, S_1, S_L, S_{end}\$

**Inputs**: **CC**
**Outputs**: **LDA**, **LDB**, **W**, **OP**

You have all what you need to sinthesize the FSM, come back if you need help with that too.

Comment: Lol ehhh... Thanks for the help :). It helped me construct the ASM chart... But yeah I still don't think I get how you go about making an FSM to control it. I ended up just having a series of and gates (four of them for the outputs) and just connected them to CC so they produced the required output when CC was the right value.

Comment: you **need** a flip flop barrier for this to work since the ALU you are using is synchronous.

Comment: So what would you store in the flip flops?

Comment: You can't synthesize an FSM if you don't know anything about them... review the fsm architecture and come back